# Sticky Sidebar with TOC in twenty-twenty-four

Tags: posts

I'm looking for a way to have a sticky table of contents in a sidebar (for posts only) in Theme twenty-twenty-four. I'm using template 'Single with Sidebar' and I've edited the sidebar pattern so it only shows the TOC (using one of the TOC plugins) and the search button but I'm struggling to find a way to make them sticky.
I'd really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Access the 'Single with Sidebar' template and wrap the column housing the sidebar template part in a group block. Then change position of that group block from default to sticky.